# Dictionary comprehension with lambda returns memory addresses as values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, lambda

I am trying to use lambda expressions within a dictionary comprehension like this:

```
d = {k: lambda v, k = k : v == True if not (i%2) else "Not True" for k in range(1,11)}
```

However, the outputs are a bit strange:

```
{1: <function <dictcomp>.<lambda> at 0x7fe5b714f510>, 
2: <function <dictcomp>.<lambda> at 0x7fe5b714f488>, (...)}
```

If I do this;

```
v = lambda k: True if not (k%2) else "Not True"

d_1 = {k : v(k) for k in range(1,11)}
```

produces the (desired) output:

```
{1: 'Not True', 2: True, 3: 'Not True', 4: True, 5: 'Not True', 6: True, 7: 'Not True', 8: True, 9: 'Not True', 10: True}
```

if I `print(v)` without (), the output is very similar to the previous dictionary values:

```
 <function <lambda> at 0x7fe5b7136e18>.
```

I think I am missing a call to the lambda function, but this does not work either:

```
d = {k: lambda v, k = k : v(k) == True if not (i%2) else False for k in range(1,11)}
```

How can I make the call to the lambda function within the comprehension?

Comment: You don't need the lambda: `{k: not (i%2) for k in range(1,11)}`

Comment: What I would like, is for me to be able to choose the values (as in the string "Not True" instead of just booleans, I will edit the question to make this more clear.  I also want to learn how to use lambdas in comprehension to do more interesting things in the future.

Comment: If you set your value to a lambda, it will be a lambda. If you set it to the result of calling a lambda, it will be the result of calling a lambda. I am not sure I understand the issue.

Comment: I want the result of the lambda to be the values of the dictionary.

Comment: Then you need to call the lambda. A lambda is a regular function, so you can use `(lambda ...: ...)(k)`. But that's silly when you can just write out the expression inside the lambda as @PeterWood suggests.

Comment: And how do you intend to evaluate a lambda that depends on the value?

Comment: You call a lambda function like any other, using `()`, so, in general, `(lambda x: ...)(some_arg)` will work, but a lambda doesn't make any sense here. It's just obfuscating something that should be straightforward and adding an unnecessary function-call overhead.

Comment: My interest is in the method itself.  The code is useless, but does iteration, control flow and expression evaluation, in a comprehension.  A fun finger exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the following

```
d = {k: (lambda k: True if not (k%2) else "Not True")(k) for k in range(1,11)}
```

However, the code looks super unreadable in my opinion. I would just use a list comprehension to filter out the even and odd numbers if that's what you're ultimately trying to do. And since your desired dictionary has indexes as keys, a list should be just fine for whatever it is you're trying to do. If you REALLY need it to be a dict, you can easily turn that filtered list into a dict

```
_d = [True if not (k%2) else "Not True" for k in range(1,11)]
d = dict(zip(range(1,11), _d))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you.  This works precisely as intended.  I hope you can understand that, what I am trying to do is just understand how lambdas can be called and use in list/tuple/dict comprehensions.  The function itself is useless, but it's a very fun finger exercise, which you have solved.
  
This thing has been on my head for /days/.  Thank you!